# Where's my Open-With gVim context menu option in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, gvim, text-editing, context-menu

I have gVim installed.  Under Vista and XP, this offered me an addition to either the object context menu of "Edit with gVim", or an addtion to the "Open With" context menu of "gVim".  This would let me send arbitrary files to gVim for editing.

Under Windows 7 64-bit, I have installed gVim -- twice, as it happens -- and there's no menu item.

How do I add an option to send arbitrary files to gVim for viewing/editing?

Comment: Old thread, but the latest vim (7.3) takes care of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a link on the internet which describes what to do: http://davidvielmetter.com/?p=1094

> If you want to have the same context menu functionality you got from gVim
>   in 32-bit Windows you’ll need to make the following changes to the
>   `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\]` key in the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Vim]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Vim\command] 
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe \"%1\""
```

The page includes a .reg fragment which will work for gVim 7.3

Answer (score 4):

Version 7.3 fixes this problem. Use the "self-installing executable". http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

Answer (score 3):

It should work out of the box on Windows 7 32-bit. I have gotten it to work on my Windows 7 RC machine.

If you want this to work on Windows 64-bit (any edition), then follow the [Fix Missing GVim Context Menu instructions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_missing_gvim_context_menu_in_Windows) from the gvim website.

Comment: Ah, you are right -- I am Windows 7-64.  Didn't realize that would make a difference, but of course it would.

Answer (score 0):

you could install the "right" binaries as well: http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/downloads/list. its 'install.bat' should create the right registry entries for you (plus the fact that you have a 64bit binary :))

Comment: Even better.  Didn't know there was a 64-bit build.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my complete directions for building GVim 7.2 for x64 and for creating the setup file.

GVim gets installed to "Program Files" as it should, printing works fine, and the integrated menus all work like a charm.

Directions & link to setup file:
http://ionipti.blogspot.com/2010/04/build-gvim-72-x64-and-create-installer.html