# How can I set a particular shortcut key for an item in the Windows 7 Explorer right-click context menu?

Tags: windows-7, vim, windows-explorer, gvim, context-menu

For me, this issue is specific to opening files through the context menu with gVIm, but it probably applies to more general situations too.

In particular, I want to get gVim to open a file with a single key press from the Windows 7 context menu.

In Windows XP, I could just right click, and type v, and my file (of any extension) would open for editing in gVim. In Windows 7, there seems to be another item using the v shortcut ("Restore previous versions"), so now when I type v the "Edit with Vim" option is highlighted but doesn't instantly run (hitting v subsequently toggles between the 2 items).

There seems to be no context item using the shortcut g, so perhaps I can change it to that. However, I can't find how to do that. Can anyone explain?

Other questions on SU (such as [this](https://superuser.com/q/37495/91656), and [this](https://superuser.com/q/34704/91656)) focus on how to add extra items to the context menu, but don't seem to cover how to specify a particular shortcut key. They are very close to what I'm trying to do, but not the same, so this is not a duplicate question of those.

Comment: Have you considered disabling the offending menu item? Look at [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) to enable/disable items in the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I use vim constantly under Windows, and I really miss the ability to use right-click + <kbd>v</kbd> to instantly open a file (or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd> if going mouse-free in Explorer).  I have also never once found a use for the "Restore previous versions" feature which has hijacked 'v'!

So I found an article that explains how to remove the "Restore previous versions" menu item via registry edits.  I never use this menu item anyway, and I don't miss it.  Besides, they provide a registry file to restore the menu item, should you ever need it.

http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/170079-restore-previous-versions-restore-remove-context-menu.html

I'll capture the reg files here for posterity.

Remove:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]
```

Add:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut key for a context menu item can be set by adding a `&` symbol before the character you want to use.

E.g.: `Edit &file with Vim` would allow you to execute the command by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>f</kbd> on Windows 7).

[Screenshot of registry entry for shortcut key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enQlk.png) (sorry, I'm not allowed to embedd the picture directly yet)

As an example, I've created a GitHub Gist for adding a context menu entry, which opens a selected file within the Vim editor included in Git Bash for Windows.

See here: https://gist.github.com/dwettstein/e5349a12852a7aadfda419e76124919c